# How to allow user to click an item from a server-rendered list in Next.js/React?

Tags: next.js, onclick, prisma, react-server-components

pretty new to react/next.js and am having trouble with something I assume is pretty basic. However, I can't seem to find any answers that apply to my specific situation.

Basically, on page load I have a component that returns a list of songs with artist names via a simple prisma query. I would like the user to be able to click on a song, and for the sake of simplicity, display the song name and artist name in the console. What do I do? Here's the code for the component "StemList" that returns the list of songs:

```
import prisma from "@/components/stemdatabase"
export async function getStems(stemType) {
    return prisma.stems.findMany({
        where: {
            stem_type: stemType
        }
    })
}

export default async function StemList({ stemType }) {
    const stems = await getStems(stemType)

    return (
        <>
            {stems.map((stem) => (
                <ul className='song-title' key={stem.id} stemType={stemType}>
                    {stem.song_name} - {stem.artist_name}
                </ul>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

I tried including an onClick property, but I quickly found out that this cannot be used on a server side component. I also can't convert this to a client component because I'm querying my db file. I can't seem to find a suitable/easy alternative to onClick, even though I feel like this should be a pretty basic bit of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap a client component inside a server component and then pass your list as a prop through to the client.

Your server component loads the list:

```
import prisma from "@/components/stemdatabase"

export async function getStems(stemType) {
    return prisma.stems.findMany({
        where: {
            stem_type: stemType
        }
    })
}

export default async function StemList({ stemType }) {
    const stems = await getStems(stemType)
    return <InteractiveStemList stems={stems} stemType={stemType} />
}
```

And your client component makes it interactive:

```
"use client";

export default function InteractiveStemList({ stems, stemType }) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {stems.map((stem) => (
                <li className='song-title' key={stem.id} stemType={stemType}>
                    <a onClick={/* callback goes here */}>{stem.song_name} - {stem.artist_name}</a>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

You can also use [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) to make your click trigger something on the server side.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thank you so much Minn, this worked beautifully.